# Cannot disable back button in React Native on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

In my `App.js` I have the following:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import Main from './js/screens/main';
import Page from './js/screens/page';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const headerOptions = {
  headerLeft: () => null,
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={headerOptions}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={Main}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Page"
          component={Page}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

This disables the back button on both the `Main` and the `Page` screens if I run in the web. When I run on Android, however, the back button appears on the `Page` screen, although not the `Main` screen. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try giving the "options={{ headShown: false }}" property to the page you don't want to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "Platform" ?

You need to add import "Platform", next to "NavigationContainer"

```
import { NavigationContainer, Platform } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

and after check with a simple if, just after your variable headerOptions add that :

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android')
headerOptions.headerLeft = () => null;
```

If it's not good after that, try with params `headerBackVisible`

Answer (score 0):

You can use headerOptions in Stack.Screen to disable

```
 return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={Main}
          options={headerOptions}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Page"
          component={Page}
          options={headerOptions}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```